# When creating a new user with a order, how to email the new user login details

Tags: commerce, rules

I am using [Commerce Admin Order Advanced](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_admin_order_advanced). It allows the following extras when creating an order in Drupal Commerce

- Search users by email or profile name before creating the order
- Select existing customer profiles before creating the order Validates
- Check a new customers email against existing customers to prevent duplicates
- Moves customer profiles to the top of the admin order form
- Provides copy address profile functionality on the admin order
  interface (uses the same settings as the checkout pane for this
  feature)

But it also will create a new user with an order, however there is no email sent to the new user with a one time link to login and set a password.

Does anyone know how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)

The Rule is as follows.

**Events**
After updating an existing commerce order

**Conditions**
Data value is empty - commerce-order:owner:last-login

**Actions**
Send account e-mail

The reason why I have used this **Event** rather than 'After creating a new order' is to do with how this 'Commerce Admin Order Advanced' module works. You create the order before adding line items. And since I only need this email to be sent when a certain product type is created, this should suffice, hence I add the following **condition**

Order contains products of particular product types - Bespoke (an arbitrary product type)

But in order to prevent these emails being sent again should an admin update the order again, I have added the following extra **Condition**

Data comparison - commerce-order:created == commerce-order-unchanged:changed